# Scheduling multiple Quartz jobs in Topshelf

Tags: quartz.net, topshelf

Reading the documentation for Topshelf integrations here: https://github.com/dtinteractive/Topshelf.Integrations

And it seems like it should be as simple as scheduling multiple quartz jobs within the `HostFactory` but it looks like the second scheduled job is the only one that's running.

I'm not really sure how to proceed from here. But I need to schedule two jobs that run on different schedules. The first is supposed to be run daily while the second gets run hourly.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HostFactory.Run(x =>                                 
        {
            x.ScheduleQuartzJobAsService(q =>
                q.WithJob(() => JobBuilder.Create<TmsIdImportTask>().Build())
                    .AddTrigger(() =>
                        TriggerBuilder.Create()
                            .WithSimpleSchedule(builder => builder
                                .WithIntervalInMinutes(Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ScheduleImportFrequencyInMinutes"]))
                                .RepeatForever()).Build())
            );

            x.ScheduleQuartzJobAsService(q =>
                q.WithJob(() => JobBuilder.Create<ImportTmsXMLTask>().Build())
                    .AddTrigger(() => TriggerBuilder.Create().WithSimpleSchedule(builder =>
                        builder.WithIntervalInMinutes(Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TMSImportFrequencyInMinutes"]))
                        .RepeatForever()).Build())
                        );


            x.RunAsLocalSystem();

            var description = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceDescription"];
            x.SetDescription(description);

            var displayName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceDisplayName"];
            x.SetDisplayName(displayName);

            var serviceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceName"];
            x.SetServiceName(serviceName);                       
        });       
    }
```

Comment: Can't you put the Quartz initialization inside your service class `Start()` and shutdown on `Stop()` methods? Why use this integration at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a second service or punt on the Topshelf-Quartz integration and have a service that initializes both Quartz instances and will shut them down.

Topshelf will only host a single [service] process, by design. You can't manage or monitor stuff to any useful degree if Topshelf is hosting multiple processes. It just ends up being an unsustainable pattern.

Answer (score 8):

I believe the reason you are having an issue is because you're using

```
x.ScheduleQuartzJobAsService
```

instead of

```
x.ScheduleQuartzJob
```

I'm just using Quartz for the first time, but I have like 20 different schedules running all within the same host

Comment: x.SchedulQuartzJob (extension) does not exist in HostConfigurator, can you show me how did you do it?

Comment: @VJPPaz ScheduleQuartzJob is in the library TopShelf.Quartz